# Powershell directory structured into json format

Tags: json, powershell

Hello I am new to powershell.

I am trying to create a directory structured into json format using powershell. similar to these picture below

[Example json format of directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCEe8.png)

I have researched some ways into doing this and found this, is their a similar or better way into naming directory and files into json format.

```
function Add-Tabstops{
    param($Count)
    $tabs = ""
    for($i=0; $i -lt $Count; $i++){$tabs += "  "}
    return $tabs
}

function Output-JsonChildren{
    param($Path, $Level = 1)
    return $(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{
        (Add-Tabstops $Level) +
        "{`n" + 
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"name`"`: `"$($_.Name)`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) + 
        "`"children`": ["+ 
        $(if($_.psiscontainer){"`n" + (Output-JsonChildren -Path $_.FullName -Level ($Level+2))+ "`n" + (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1))}) +
        "]`n" + 
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level)) +
        "}"
    }) -join ",`n"
  
}

$JSON = Output-JsonChildren -Path "C:\Users\Glen\Desktop\democontainer" |   Out-File "C:\Users\Glen\Desktop\democontainer\test.json"

"["
$JSON
"]"
```

Comment: If this works for you, why not just use it? AS fpr `is their a similar or better way into naming directory and files into json format?`What do you mean by this? There are always better ways to do things, but there needs to be a goal for what better means. I.E., faster, more elegant code, less code, etc. You are not saying why you'd want to change this. As for `example... using hasttable`, the PowerShell help files show this, by example, as well as many articles/examples/videos all over the web. [What did you search for?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+hashtables%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function  build-json {
    param (
        [string]$fullPath
    )
    $hashtable = @{}
    $directories = get-childitem $fullPath -Directory
    try{
    $files = (get-childitem $fullPath -File)
    if($null -eq $files) {
        $hashtable.files = @()
    }
    else {
        $hashtable.files = [array]$files.Name
    }
    } 
    catch {
        echo 'xxx'
    }

    $hashtable.directories = @{}
    foreach($directory in $directories) {
        $element = Split-Path $directory.fullname -Leaf
        $hashtable.directories.$element = build-json -fullPath $directory.FullName -hashtable $hashtable
    }
    return $hashtable
}

$sourcefolder = 'E:\xxx\Software\yyy\python392'

$result3 = build-json -fullPath $sourcefolder -hashtable @{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

You will need to write a little recursive function which walks through the dictionaries and collects the information for you.

You can use a hashtable (`@{}`) or a PowerShell object, but a hashtable is preferable.

`Get-ChildItem` and `ConvertTo-Json` are your friends

Comment: @JeremyCaney, I've closed the previous question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: would you be kind to give me an example to help started using hasttable